# Transform from Pageable.getSort() to List<Order> to sort a query made by Criteria API in a Spring repository custom

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I've implemented one my custom Spring repository which receives in input a `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` object. This `Pageable` object has the following sort property (for example): `id: DESC,name: ASC`.

I need to convert the `pageable.getSort()` property into a `List<Order>` in order to set an order for the `criteriaQuery.orderBy(List<Order>)` method.

In order to retrieve a paged result, I used the `new PageImpl` passing it the `pageable` object, but this not manage the ordering.

```
TypedQuery<Entity> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
typedQuery.setFirstResult(pageable.getOffset());
typedQuery.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());
Page<Entity> page = new PageImpl<Entity>(typedQuery.getResultList(), pageable, typedQuery.getMaxResults());
return page;
```

Any suggests?
Thanks, Andrea

Comment: You can use `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository#getQuery(org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification<T>, org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)`, but isn't it satisfy your requirement ?

Comment: Solved using a Spring's class QueryUtils and its method toOrders(): `criteriaQuery.orderBy(QueryUtils.toOrders(pageable.getSort(), root, criteriaBuilder));`

Comment: @AndreaBevilacqua you could answer your own question with you comment above. Would be nice, and it is easier to spot the answer.

Answer (score 21):

It can be done using `queryUtils`.

```
 import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils;
    criteriaQuery.orderBy(QueryUtils.toOrders(pageable.getSort(), rootEntity, criteriaBuilder));
```